# MySQL - broken accented characters with asp classic (pt-br)

Tags: mysql, charset

Please, I am having this issue that is broking my brain!

The site `<title>` has the word **Promoção** and the Mysql database also has words with accented characters.

If I use `Response.CodePage=65001` in the ASP code, the word from the database show correctly, but the word in the title show the symbol �.

If I dont use `Response.CodePage=65001` the title stay correct and the accented word from the database show �

Please, what can I do?

PS.: I already tried use use:

`charset=UTF-8` and `charset=ucs2` in the database connection

also tried

`Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"`

`Response.CodePage = 65001`

`Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"`

Comment: Also look at the `show create table {tablename}` for the database table to see the storage character set. Examine if its a database or web issue by examining data against the expected results.

Comment: Where is the text of your `<title>` stored? Is it in the page? If so, is it possible the text editor you use to edit that `whatever.asp` file is working in the iso-8859-1 or the windows 1252 character set rather than unicode?

Comment: The `<title>` text is in the own page. Yes, saving the asp file as UTF-8 using a Notepad, solve the database word issue. But is weird because I always use the Dreamwaver editor and this never happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question, the page.asp need to be save as Unicode (UTF-8) and the top of the each page need the line `<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>`